# jabber connection to another servers doesn't work under firewall

Tags: firewall, port, xmpp

When firewall turned on, jabber server do not connect to another jabber servers. When turn off - all good. The config is (deny by default, allow all outgoing connections):

```
Source  Protocol    Remote port Local port  Type
All     tcp     All     22      Allow
All     tcp     All     465     Allow
All     tcp     All     995     Allow
All     udp     53      All     Allow
All     udp     123     All     Allow
All     icmp    -/-     -/-     Allow
All     tcp     25      All     Allow
All     tcp     All     5222        Allow
All     tcp     All     5269        Allow
```

Connect to 5222 port established good and connection to other users on this server also good. But to another server's users nothing work.

btw: mail is working good in this config of firewall.

What's wrong?

Comment: var/log/ejabberd log says: =INFO REPORT==== 2013-05-31 16:59:13 ===
I(<0.926.0>:ejabberd_s2s_out:235) : s2s connection: domain.com -> jabber.org (remote server not found)

Comment: resolved. Thank you. I've added Local port ALL -> Remote 5269.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure 5269 is also open on the server-side.

Are you using SSL server connections? If so, you'll need 5223 on both sides.

http://www.accessgrid.org/agdp/guide/ports/1.03/x112.html

Comment: yes, 5269 is opened. Without firewall all work good. 5223 don't using, because we have SSL on 5222.

Comment: You could also just allow all traffic from Server A to Server B in the firewall (both sides).